# I have an array of Singles that I need to pass into a function as an IntPtr

Tags: vb.net

I've read lots of posts on pointers, but I still don't know how to do the above.

This is the function:

```
Private Shared Function ca_array_put_callback(ByVal datatype As CaRequestDataTypeEnum, ByVal count As CaUnsignedLong, ByVal chid As IntPtr, ByVal PValue As IntPtr, _
                                       ByVal pfunc As IntPtr, ByVal UserArgs As CaPvInfo) As CaErrorCodeEnum
```

`PValue` is the bit I'm struggling with passing to the function.

This is my code so far:

```
Public Function putvalue_Callback(setvalue As Single) As CaErrorCodeEnum
        'write a single precision value to the pv
        Dim setvalues(0) As Single
        setvalues(0) = setvalue
        Dim ptr_Set_Values As IntPtr
        ptr_Set_Values = setvalues ' This is the line with the error
        Return putvaluesarray(setvalues)
    End Function
```

(`chid` is assigned a value by an external function so can't get syntax from there)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. Intptr and marshalling mostly used to call unmanaged dll functions. No need to use it on yourcode

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `IntPtr` to an array, like this:

```
Dim myArray() As Single = {0, 1, 2, 3}
Dim pinned As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(myArray, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim ptr As IntPtr = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject()
' Use ptr...
pinned.Free()
```

You need to call `Free` afterwards to make sure that you release the memory that you allocated.  Obviously, though, you cannot do that until after you have used the `IntPtr`, so you may need to restructure your code a little bit to compensate for that.

As qwr rightly pointed out, however, this does seem strange.  I would have expected the function to which you are passing the `IntPtr` to be a declaration to an unmanaged API call of some sort.  It's unusual that you have a shared method in managed code which is asking for an `IntPtr` parameter.  Is that just because it's a wrapper around some underlying unmanaged call, or is there something more sinister going on?

Comment: Hi, ca_array_put_callback is a wrapper to a C library (ca.dll - an EPICs library). I'm trying to call this wrappered function but am struggling to pass the correct type of parameters.

Comment: Are you saying that you are still having trouble, even after my explanation?  If so, with which part are you still having trouble, or in what part have I confused you?

Comment: Comment timed out. I'll try your code and let you know how I get on. The next parameter is also causing problem, but I think it could be a problem with the wrapper. Many Thanks. Kristian

Comment: Yep - That's now working, i.e. I can call the function now and get no errors, but funcytion not working as expected. Thanks